# How to update a linked server connection string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I'm using below statement for addling a linked server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'north',
@srvproduct = '',
@provider = 'MSDASQL',
@provstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.100.147;UID=sa;PWD=xxxx;'
```

Now I want to update the linked server connection string, for example the server name and etc.
Is there any statement to do it?

Comment: Just as easy to drop & recreate the object...

Comment: My remote database is using for replication, isn't there any problem if I do it?

Comment: My remote database uses "transactional replication" and it is as "publisher" an my database wants to connect to it with linked server

Comment: @Raymond Morphy, so, which of the servers has the linked server defined? Your database? if so, then it's safe to drop and recreate the linked server.

Comment: I linked to that database which is doing replicatiion?

Answer (score 3):

To change server name of the linked server use [sp_setnetname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190318.aspx). Changing other things doesn't make sense (eg provider) which is why there is no alter proc.

In this case it won't work because you haven't followed the sp_addlinkedserver example. In fact, I can't see why you'd set up a linked server to SQL Server this way. You'd use [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx) for credentials too

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
  @server = 'north',
  @srvproduct = 'SQL Server'
GO
EXEC sp_setnetname 'north', '192.168.100.147'
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'north', NULL, NULL, 'sa', 'XXXX'
GO
```

If you don't want to do it this way, then drop and recreate it however you want. That is, you *have* to drop and recreate it because you have set this up in a non-standard fashion